# Show that a square with vertices t, u, v, w has center 1/4 (t+u+v+w).

Tags: geometry, vector-spaces, euclidean-geometry

I need a help with this question!

Show that a square with vertices t, u, v, w has center 1/4
(t+u+v+w).

Answer (score 1):

Note that $1/4(t+u+v+w)$, if t, u, v, and w are integers gives the mean(average) of the four numbers. This may help in your understanding of how the center of the square is $1/4(t+u+v+w)$.

Comment: I figured this one out, let P be the center point,

Let u, w be diagonals, and t, v be diagonals.

p=u/2 + w/2,
p=t/2 + v/2,

2p = u/2 + w/2 + t/2 + v/2,

p = 1/4(u+w+t+v),

:D